# .NET framework 4.5 not recognizing geometery data type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, spatial

I'm trying to set up my project to be able to use the spatial extensions, but I'm getting the following error when I try to create the .edmx:

> warning 6005: The data type 'geometry' is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version

Then it just creates the edmx and excludes the columns of geometry type from the model. Everything compiles, I just can't use the geometry stuff cause it's not there!

My project targets the .NET 4.5 framework and is using Entity Framework 5.0. One caveat is that I am using MySql. I've installed the MySql .NET Connector 6.7.4 along with all the updates for Visual Studio and the like which according to everything I've read should complete the set up to allow me to do what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know what I could be missing or doing wrong?? I feel like I've been beating my head against the wall for days! I've gotten to the point I'm starting to question if I even know how to use Visual Studio. Just to double check - if the project properties page's dropdown for "Target framework" is set to ".NET Framework 4.5" that means I'm using 4.5 right?! And if the properties section for the Entity Framework reference says "5.0" it's 5.0 right? Even if the runtime version says "4.0.30319"? I installed 5.0, so I'm not sure why runtime would be different...

I would greatly appreciate any guidance at all! I'm going nuts here. I've even tried to add the property manually, but it wouldn't let me add a new mapping and the build would fail!!

Thanks in advance!

ADDITIONAL INFO: I don't know if this matters or not, but I didn't create the project initially with these versions. The original MySql Connector was 6.6.5.  Could that make a difference? Like is there somewhere that needed an updated version that I haven't changed? I changed my web.config Membership Provider section, since that had the version number in it, but otherwise, I really didn't see it anywhere else. The dlls (mysql.data and mysql.data.entity) have been replaced in the references, but the mysql.web is still 6.6.5 because I didn't get another version of the dll when I installed 6.7.4

Comment: To answer a small part of your question, `Runtime Version` is the version of .NET the dll is built against. [`4.0.30319.17929` and higher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions) is .NET 4.5 (it would also report `4.0.30319` for .NET 4.0). Anything built with 3.5 reports `v2.0.50727`

Answer (score 0):

Geometry is not a CLR type, instead a SQL Server database type. DbGeography and DbGeometry are the types available in .NET 4.5, but you need to refer System.Data.Spatial in your code.

As mentioned in Rick Strahl's blog(http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Jun/21/Basic-Spatial-Data-with-SQL-Server-and-Entity-Framework-50),
there is no native CLR spatial type. The DbGeography and DbGeometry types are specific to Entity Framework and live on those assemblies. They will also work for general purpose, non-database spatial data manipulation, but then you are forced into having a dependency on System.Data.Entity.